# Implementing C#-like events in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, events

I'm used to programming in C#, and one thing I miss about Java is that it doesn't seem to have C#'s nice built-in event handling capabilities:

```
// define event signature
public delegate void SomeEventHandler();

class SomeEventGenerator {
    // define subscribable event property
    public event SomeEventHandler SomeEvent;

    protected void OnSomeEvent() {
        if (SomeEvent != null) {
            SomeEvent();
        }
    }
}

class SomeEventClient {
    public SomeEventClient(SomeEventGenerator eg) {
        // subscribe
        eg.SomeEvent += new SomeEventHandler(eg_SomeEvent);
        // do some stuff
        // unsubscribe
        eg.SomeEvent -= new SomeEventHandler(eg_SomeEvent);
    }

    private void eg_SomeEvent() {
        // handle event
    }
}
```

What's the best way to get something similar and lightweight in Java/Android which has the ability to subscribe/unsubscribe multiple event clients and call all subscribed clients at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would want to look into the concept of listeners in java. I found a very good article called "C# from a Java developers perspective" that you might want to check out.

http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html

Comment: So you have to do it yourself.  There is a small section about events in that article which I found helpful.  I set up some `OnSomeEventListener` interfaces, and `addListener` / `removeListener` / `callListeners` methods backed by a `Vector<OnSomeEventListener>`.